# openssl parse error c# aws lambda mqtt

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I am trying to create an aws-lambda function in c# that publishes to an aws-iot thing via mqtt.

For now, all I am trying to do is get it to publish a string message to a test topic that I am subscribed to.

This code works perfectly when running it via a unit test and the string is received on my iot thing.

when deploying to aws the code publishes without error but when invoking the code I receive the following response.

```
{
"errorType" : "OpenSslCryptographicException",
"errorMessage" : "error:23076072:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_parse:parse error",
"stackTrace"   : [
    "at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslPkcs12Reader.Decrypt(String password)",
    "at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.PkcsFormatReader.TryReadPkcs12(OpenSslPkcs12Reader pfx, String password, Boolean single, ICertificatePal& readPal, List`1& readCerts)",
    "at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.PkcsFormatReader.TryReadPkcs12(SafeBioHandle bio, String password, Boolean single, ICertificatePal& readPal, List`1& readCerts)",
    "at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBio(SafeBioHandle bio, String password)",
    "at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromFile(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)",
    "at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)",
    "at RaspberryPi.Function.SendMQTTMessage(String sTopic, String sMessage)",
    "at RaspberryPi.Function.FunctionHandler(SkillRequest oSkillRequest, ILambdaContext oContext)",
    "at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , ContextInfo )"
]
}
```

my code to do the publish is

```
public bool SendMQTTMessage(string sTopic, string sMessage)
    {
        X509Certificate2 clientCert = new X509Certificate2(fileName: "./Certificates/be427151d2.pfx", password: "****", keyStorageFlags: X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);
        X509Certificate caCert = new X509Certificate(fileName: "./Certificates/RootCA.pem");

        MqttClient client = new MqttClient("*****", 8883, true, caCert, clientCert, MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2); //M2MQTT

        client.Connect("clientid1");

        client.Publish(sTopic, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sMessage));

        return client.IsConnected;

    }
```